# how to create gwt gae with app engine modules using google eclipse plugin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, gae-eclipse-plugin, maven-gae-plugin

How to create a new GWT and GAE project with modules using google eclipse plugin in Java? I tried using make a new web applications from the eclipse, but it just create me a GWT and GAE project without modules.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to first create a WTP project using GPE, because to use modules you'll need to create an EAR project.  This is described here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform

You'll create modules, which will each be a dynamic web project.  Your GWT app will be one of those.  And follow the instructions for modules here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

Note that there will be two Google related items when you right-click your project: Google and Google App Engine WTP.  Commands related to app engine in the Google menu don't seem to work.  Instead use the app engine related commands in the Google App Engine WTP menu.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. I tried to add dynamic web project, but after that I can't add GWT in it. Usually by right clicking it *Google* > *Web Toolkits Settings..*, but now that settings doesn't appear.

Comment: And I saw it's different from what com.google.appengine.archetypes:appengine-skeleton-archetype generate.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it is an open feature request to do this programmatically:
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3584
and
https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=121

There is a proposed workaround:

> GWT Compile and copy the /war/ output into a standard Dynamic Web Project.

I have tested this workaround and it works. Simply copy the *Google Web Applications Project's* "war" directory into the web content directory (default: "WebContent") of a stub *Dynamic Web Project*.

For the local AppEngine dev server for Dynamic Web Projects and EAR projects it is important that project names do not contain a space. Moreover, this also applies to the AppEngine agent file path, see [Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530157/error-opening-zip-file-or-jar-manifest-missing-c-program).

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a new GWT and GAE project with modules using google eclipse plugin in Java?

Do check in each option to create project with sample code.

- **Use Google Web Toolkit**
- **User Google App Engine**
- **Sample Code** : It creates sample code with module as you expect.

Comment: Hi TBM, thanks for your response. I tried to check each options to create project with sample code, but it just gave me as usual without modules.

Comment: what do you mean by modules in GWT? if you find than your project contain {module name}.gwt.xml..that's it.

Comment: Not gwt module, but app engine modules as described in here : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/